# scs2ascii and SSLv2_client_method errors while running the make command during the installation of tn5250 on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I'm desperately trying to use Linux solely.  In order for me to do this, I must be able to use tn5250 for work.  I refuse to do a dual boot with a Windows OS and would appreciate it if I do not have to use a VM.  My problem is with the installation of tn5250 during the make command on Linux.

I obtained the package(s) form SourceForge [here][1].  I downloaded the tn5250_0.16.5-5woody1_i386.deb and the tn5250-0.17.4.tar.gz.  The former would only work if I ran it through wine, but it would not remember any login credentials or any macros I would set within the program itself.  The ladder is the one I'm having a problem getting installed.

I ran the following commands to install the ladder...

```
./configure --prefix=/opt --with-ssl  
make
```

Below is a terminal print-out of the make command...

```
dustin@dustin-laptop:~/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4$ **make**  
make  all-recursive  
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4'  
Making all in lib5250  
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4/lib5250'  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT buffer.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/buffer.Tpo" -c -o buffer.lo buffer.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/buffer.Tpo" ".deps/buffer.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/buffer.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
mkdir .libs  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT buffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/buffer.Tpo -c buffer.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/buffer.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT buffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/buffer.Tpo -c buffer.c -o buffer.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT conf.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/conf.Tpo" -c -o conf.lo conf.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/conf.Tpo" ".deps/conf.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/conf.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT conf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/conf.Tpo -c conf.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/conf.o  
conf.c: In function '**tn5250_config_load**':  
conf.c:258:5: **warning**: ignoring return value of 'fgets', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]  
     fgets (buf, sizeof (buf) - 1, f);  
     ^  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT conf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/conf.Tpo -c conf.c -o conf.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT dbuffer.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/dbuffer.Tpo" -c -o dbuffer.lo dbuffer.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/dbuffer.Tpo" ".deps/dbuffer.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/dbuffer.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT dbuffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/dbuffer.Tpo -c dbuffer.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/dbuffer.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT dbuffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/dbuffer.Tpo -c dbuffer.c -o dbuffer.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT debug.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/debug.Tpo" -c -o debug.lo debug.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/debug.Tpo" ".deps/debug.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/debug.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT debug.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/debug.Tpo -c debug.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/debug.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT debug.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/debug.Tpo -c debug.c -o debug.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT display.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/display.Tpo" -c -o display.lo display.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/display.Tpo" ".deps/display.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/display.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT display.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/display.Tpo -c display.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/display.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT display.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/display.Tpo -c display.c -o display.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT field.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/field.Tpo" -c -o field.lo field.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/field.Tpo" ".deps/field.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/field.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT field.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/field.Tpo -c field.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/field.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT field.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/field.Tpo -c field.c -o field.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT macro.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/macro.Tpo" -c -o macro.lo macro.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/macro.Tpo" ".deps/macro.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/macro.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT macro.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/macro.Tpo -c macro.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/macro.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT macro.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/macro.Tpo -c macro.c -o macro.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT menu.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/menu.Tpo" -c -o menu.lo menu.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/menu.Tpo" ".deps/menu.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/menu.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT menu.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/menu.Tpo -c menu.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/menu.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT menu.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/menu.Tpo -c menu.c -o menu.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT printsession.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/printsession.Tpo" -c -o printsession.lo printsession.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/printsession.Tpo" ".deps/printsession.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/printsession.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT printsession.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/printsession.Tpo -c printsession.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/printsession.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT printsession.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/printsession.Tpo -c printsession.c -o printsession.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT record.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/record.Tpo" -c -o record.lo record.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/record.Tpo" ".deps/record.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/record.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT record.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/record.Tpo -c record.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/record.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT record.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/record.Tpo -c record.c -o record.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT scrollbar.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/scrollbar.Tpo" -c -o scrollbar.lo scrollbar.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/scrollbar.Tpo" ".deps/scrollbar.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/scrollbar.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT scrollbar.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/scrollbar.Tpo -c scrollbar.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/scrollbar.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT scrollbar.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/scrollbar.Tpo -c scrollbar.c -o scrollbar.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT scs.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/scs.Tpo" -c -o scs.lo scs.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/scs.Tpo" ".deps/scs.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/scs.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT scs.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/scs.Tpo -c scs.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/scs.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT scs.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/scs.Tpo -c scs.c -o scs.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT session.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/session.Tpo" -c -o session.lo session.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/session.Tpo" ".deps/session.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/session.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT session.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/session.Tpo -c session.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/session.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT session.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/session.Tpo -c session.c -o session.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT sslstream.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/sslstream.Tpo" -c -o sslstream.lo sslstream.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/sslstream.Tpo" ".deps/sslstream.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/sslstream.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT sslstream.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sslstream.Tpo -c sslstream.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/sslstream.o  
sslstream.c: In function '**ssl_getTelOpt**':  
sslstream.c:179:14: **warning**: type of '**what**' defaults to '**int**' [-Wimplicit-int]  
 static char *ssl_getTelOpt(what)  
              ^  
sslstream.c: In function '**ssl_log_SB_buf**':  
sslstream.c:310:4: **warning**: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]  
    fprintf(tn5250_logfile,ssl_getTelOpt(type=*buf++));  
    ^  
sslstream.c: In function '**tn5250_ssl_stream_init**':  
sslstream.c:372:16: **warning**: implicit declaration of function '**SSLv2_client_method**' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
         meth = SSLv2_client_method();           
                ^  
sslstream.c:372:14: **warning**: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]  
         meth = SSLv2_client_method();           
              ^  
sslstream.c:375:14: **warning**: assignment discards '**const**' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]  
         meth = SSLv3_client_method();           
              ^  
sslstream.c:378:14: **warning**: assignment discards '**const**' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]  
         meth = SSLv23_client_method();           
              ^  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT sslstream.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sslstream.Tpo -c sslstream.c -o sslstream.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT stream.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/stream.Tpo" -c -o stream.lo stream.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/stream.Tpo" ".deps/stream.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/stream.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT stream.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/stream.Tpo -c stream.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/stream.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT stream.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/stream.Tpo -c stream.c -o stream.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT telnetstr.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/telnetstr.Tpo" -c -o telnetstr.lo telnetstr.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/telnetstr.Tpo" ".deps/telnetstr.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/telnetstr.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT telnetstr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/telnetstr.Tpo -c telnetstr.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/telnetstr.o  
telnetstr.c: In function '**getTelOpt**':  
telnetstr.c:161:14: **warning**: type of '**what**' defaults to '**int**' [-Wimplicit-int]  
 static char *getTelOpt(what)  
              ^  
telnetstr.c: In function '**log_SB_buf**':  
telnetstr.c:285:4: **warning**: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]  
    fprintf(tn5250_logfile,getTelOpt(type=*buf++));  
    ^  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT telnetstr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/telnetstr.Tpo -c telnetstr.c -o telnetstr.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT terminal.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/terminal.Tpo" -c -o terminal.lo terminal.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/terminal.Tpo" ".deps/terminal.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/terminal.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT terminal.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/terminal.Tpo -c terminal.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/terminal.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT terminal.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/terminal.Tpo -c terminal.c -o terminal.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT utility.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/utility.Tpo" -c -o utility.lo utility.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/utility.Tpo" ".deps/utility.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/utility.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT utility.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/utility.Tpo -c utility.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/utility.o  
utility.c: In function '**tn5250_daemon**':  
utility.c:114:5: **warning**: implicit declaration of function '**umask**' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
     umask(0);  
     ^  
utility.c: In function '**tn5250_log_open**':  
utility.c:391:4: **warning**: implicit declaration of function '**fchmod**' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
    fchmod(fileno(tn5250_logfile), 0600);  
    ^  
utility.c: In function '**tn5250_daemon**':  
utility.c:105:7: **warning**: ignoring return value of '**chdir**', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]  
       chdir("/");  
       ^  
utility.c:111:9: **warning**: ignoring return value of '**dup**', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]  
         dup(0); dup(0);  
         ^  
utility.c:111:17: **warning**: ignoring return value of '**dup**', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]  
         dup(0); dup(0);  
                 ^  
utility.c: In function '**tn5250_run_cmd**':  
utility.c:607:12: **warning**: ignoring return value of '**system**', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]  
            system(cmd);  
            ^  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT utility.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/utility.Tpo -c utility.c -o utility.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT version.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/version.Tpo" -c -o version.lo version.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/version.Tpo" ".deps/version.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/version.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/version.Tpo -c version.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/version.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/version.Tpo -c version.c -o version.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT window.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/window.Tpo" -c -o window.lo window.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/window.Tpo" ".deps/window.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/window.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT window.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/window.Tpo -c window.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/window.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT window.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/window.Tpo -c window.c -o window.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\"  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT wtd.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/wtd.Tpo" -c -o wtd.lo wtd.c; \  
then mv -f ".deps/wtd.Tpo" ".deps/wtd.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/wtd.Tpo"; exit 1; fi  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT wtd.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/wtd.Tpo -c wtd.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/wtd.o  
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT wtd.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/wtd.Tpo -c wtd.c -o wtd.o >/dev/null 2>&1  
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o lib5250.la -rpath /opt/lib  buffer.lo conf.lo dbuffer.lo debug.lo display.lo field.lo macro.lo menu.lo printsession.lo record.lo scrollbar.lo scs.lo session.lo sslstream.lo stream.lo telnetstr.lo terminal.lo utility.lo version.lo window.lo wtd.lo  -lssl -lcrypto   
gcc -shared  .libs/buffer.o .libs/conf.o .libs/dbuffer.o .libs/debug.o .libs/display.o .libs/field.o .libs/macro.o .libs/menu.o .libs/printsession.o .libs/record.o .libs/scrollbar.o .libs/scs.o .libs/session.o .libs/sslstream.o .libs/stream.o .libs/telnetstr.o .libs/terminal.o .libs/utility.o .libs/version.o .libs/window.o .libs/wtd.o  -lssl -lcrypto  -Wl,-soname -Wl,lib5250.so.0 -o .libs/lib5250.so.0.0.0  
(cd .libs && rm -f lib5250.so.0 && ln -s lib5250.so.0.0.0 lib5250.so.0)  
(cd .libs && rm -f lib5250.so && ln -s lib5250.so.0.0.0 lib5250.so)  
ar cru .libs/lib5250.a  buffer.o conf.o dbuffer.o debug.o display.o field.o macro.o menu.o printsession.o record.o scrollbar.o scs.o session.o sslstream.o stream.o telnetstr.o terminal.o utility.o version.o window.o wtd.o  
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
ranlib .libs/lib5250.a
creating lib5250.la
(cd .libs && rm -f lib5250.la && ln -s ../lib5250.la lib5250.la)
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4/lib5250'
Making all in lp5250d
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4/lp5250d'
if gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/opt/etc\" -I../lib5250  -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT scs2ascii.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/scs2ascii.Tpo" -c -o scs2ascii.o scs2ascii.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/scs2ascii.Tpo" ".deps/scs2ascii.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/scs2ascii.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
scs2ascii.c: In function ‘**main**’:
scs2ascii.c:70:3: **warning**: implicit declaration of function ‘**scs_main**’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   scs_main (scs);
   ^
scs2ascii.c: In function ‘**scs2ascii_ff**’:
scs2ascii.c:142:3: **warning**: implicit declaration of function ‘**scs_ff**’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   scs_ff (This);
   ^
scs2ascii.c: In function ‘**scs2ascii_nl**’:
scs2ascii.c:156:3: **warning**: implicit declaration of function ‘**scs_nl**’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   scs_nl (This);
   ^
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o scs2ascii  scs2ascii.o ../lib5250/lib5250.la -lssl -lcrypto 
mkdir .libs
gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/scs2ascii scs2ascii.o  ../lib5250/.libs/lib5250.so -lssl -lcrypto  -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/opt/lib
../lib5250/.libs/lib5250.so: undefined reference to `SSLv2_client_method'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
Makefile:265: recipe for target 'scs2ascii' failed  
make[2]: *** [scs2ascii] Error 1  
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4/lp5250d'  
Makefile:335: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed  
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dustin/Downloads/Work/tn5250-0.17.4/tn5250-0.17.4'  
Makefile:226: recipe for target 'all' failed  
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: What version of `OpenSSL` do you have installed?

Comment: @bertieb 1.0.2g